# Why does macOS 11 give weird VNC screen

Tags: macos, big-sur, remote-desktop

Does anybody have problems with VNC on macOS 11+?

This is what I got after a fresh install (virtualized machine, VMware Tools version: 11333):

[image]

Here is what I've done:

- Enabled everything required at System Preferences>Security & Privacy>Privacy.
- Deleted file `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.windowserver.plist`.
- Random restart actually solves the problem sometimes but nothing what survives reboot.
- Restarting service
  `/System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -agent -restart`

  doesn't help either.

I access via Safari, the Screen Sharing app or VNC Viewer (6.21.118), all conducted from latest macOS (as of today 11.2.3) with same result. Sometimes, at least the background image is clear, but the login window (user picture and password box) is like the picture above.

What can I do more?

Comment: Why not use screen sharing instead of a vnc viewer?

Comment: I've mentioned this as per: "I access via Safari/screenSharing app or ..."

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the size of the VM video memory to at least **16 MB** and set a different screen resolution:

```
# sudo /Library/Application\ Support/VMware\ Tools/vmware-resolutionSet 1280 1024
Requested resolution: 1280x1024
Effective resolution: 1280x1024
```